# Clubsuit gives Missing $ inserted \end{equation} error

Tags: equations

I am trying to tag an equation with a card suit. My equation works fine with other labels but the suits do not work.

```
\begin{equation}
y^2 + 2 = x^3, x, y \in \mathbb{Z}. \tag{\kreuz}
\end{equation}
```

This works, but,

```
\begin{equation}
\lvert x^2 - 2y^2 \rvert = 1 \tag{\clubsuit}
\end{equation}
```

Gives error:
`Missing $ inserted \end{equation}`

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Can you please add a full  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Content inside `\tag` is not in math mode! (I am surprised too). As `\clubsuit` is to be used in math mode, add `$` around `\clubsuit`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \lvert x^2 - 2y^2 \rvert = 1 \tag{$\clubsuit$}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]